# IO.async callback problem with cats.effect in Scala

Tags: scala, callback, io, cats-effect

Im trying to rewrite a httpclient through the java11 `HttpClient` in Scala

Here is my code:

```scala
import cats.effect._
import java.net.http._
import java.net.http.HttpResponse._
import java.net.http.HttpClient._

trait HttpClients[F[_]] {
  def send(req: HttpRequest)(implicit F: Async[F]): F[HttpResponse[_]]
}

object HttpClients {
  val client: HttpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().followRedirects(Redirect.ALWAYS).build()
  def newClient[F[_] : Async](): HttpClients[F] = new HttpClients[F] {
    override def send(req: HttpRequest)(implicit F: Async[F]): F[HttpResponse[_]] = F.async { cb =>
      val resp = client.sendAsync(req, BodyHandlers.ofString())
      val s = resp.handle((res: HttpResponse[String], err: Throwable) => {
        if (err == null)
          cb(Right(res))
        else
          cb(Left(err))
      })
      s // TODO ?
      // Type missmatch
      // Required: F[Option[F[Unit]]]
      // Found:    Unit
    }
  }
}
```

the handle callback from [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#handle(java.util.function.BiFunction))

I guess the error comes from [here](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/df6861d4c682deb6da1929609ad18914d59386f7/kernel/shared/src/main/scala/cats/effect/kernel/Async.scala#L74), but I don't know how to write next.

Then I make some change:

```scala
  def newClient[F[_] : Async](): HttpClients[F] = new HttpClients[F] {
    override def send(req: HttpRequest)(implicit F: Async[F]): F[HttpResponse[_]] = F.async[HttpResponse[_]] { cb =>
      val s = Sync[F](F: Async[F]).delay {
        val resp = client.sendAsync(req, BodyHandlers.ofString())
        resp.handle((res: HttpResponse[String], err: Throwable) => {
          if (err == null)
            cb(Right(res))
          else
            cb(Left(err))
        }).join()
      }
      F.delay(s.some)
    }
  }
```

This time, there is no error, but I don't know how to get the response's body

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: return the s. Put the s as the last statement of the function

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 I tried, It's not work, it says found `(Either[Throwable, HttpResponse[_]] => Unit) => CompletableFuture[_$3]`, required `Required: (Either[Throwable, HttpResponse[_]] => Unit) => F[Option[F[Unit]]]`

Comment: Looks like you're using cats-effect 3. It's an important distinction - you probably want to use `async_`, the return value for `async` is the cancellation action. To get a body, you probably want to e.g. have a type `F[HttpResponse[String]]` instead of `F[HttpResponse[_]]` since the latter discards the fact that there's a `String` inside.

Comment: And if I'm right about cats-effect 3, you should be able to simply do `F.fromCompletableFuture(F.delay(client.sendAsync(...)))` instead of doing delay/async by hand.

Comment: @Oleg Pyzhcov Thank you very much!! Im using CE3.1.0, now Im trying to set a timeout for each request(there are parallel requests), so which way is better? set it in the client? or outside by the IO?

Comment: @Huelse I'd say if timing out is part of your domain logic, do it with IO, and if you are just trying to avoid requests hanging forever, do it on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@OlegPyzhcov already provided insight in case you are using **CE3**, this answer is using **CE2** in case that is what you wanted.

The first version of the code was correct, here is a full running example using **Ammonite** with some style improvements and ensuring a new client is created for each call and evaluation of `newClient`

```scala
// scala 2.13.5

import $ivy.`org.typelevel::cats-effect:2.5.0`

import cats.effect.{Async, IO}
import cats.syntax.all._
import java.net.URI
import java.net.http.{HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpResponse}

trait HttpClients[F[_]] {
  def send(req: HttpRequest): F[HttpResponse[String]]
}

object HttpClients {
  def newClient[F[_]](implicit F: Async[F]): F[HttpClients[F]] =
    F.delay {
      HttpClient
        .newBuilder
        .followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.ALWAYS)
        .build()
    } map { client =>
      new HttpClients[F] {
        override def send(req: HttpRequest): F[HttpResponse[String]] =
          F.async { cb =>
            client.sendAsync(req, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString).handle {
              (res: HttpResponse[String], err: Throwable) =>
                if (err == null) cb(Right(res))
                else cb(Left(err))
            }
          }
      }
    }
}

object Main {
  private val request =
    HttpRequest
      .newBuilder
      .GET
      .uri(URI.create("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala?tab=Newest"))
      .build()

  private val program = for {
    _ <- IO.delay(println("Hello, World!"))
    client <- HttpClients.newClient[IO]
    response <- client.send(request)
    _ <- IO.delay(println(response))
    _ <- IO.delay(println(response.body))
  } yield ()

  def run(): Unit = {
    program.unsafeRunSync()
  }
}

@main
def main(): Unit = {
  Main.run()
}
```

Comment: Note, I am still not sure if the HTTP client creation must be suspended or not. but in case of doubt, suspending it doesn't hurt.